# Is it possible to lock a template in Template Manager?

Tags: templates, control-panel

We have a template which is literally a template in the original sense: i.e. it contains code which is intended to be copied and pasted into a newly created template.

Is it possible to 'lock' this in anyway so this base code cannot be changed only copied to a new template where any changes can take place?

Comment: What is the template for? Any time you start copying code repeatedly is a good time to start wondering if you can centralize/reuse the main template rather than making a bunch of copies.

Answer (score 3):

I can see couple ways to do this:

1. Create a special group as copy of SuperAdmin, but w/o rights to edit specific template group, where you will keep your original templates.
2. You can activate option Save Template as files. The files still be available for modification in CP. But you can protect some of them by change file permissions.